# General Structure Sheaf Question

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In reading the Red Book of Varieties and Schemes, I am confused on this idea boxed in the image: [image: Image of problem].

Why does $F(x)=0$ for all $x \in U$ imply $F=0$? Can't we only say this if $F$ vanishes on all of $X$, the irreducible algebraic set which determines the affine coordinate ring?

Comment: Well $U$ is dense in $X$, so knowing what happens on $U$ tells you quite a bit. I'm a little worried that I'll say something that won't match with his conventions -- I'll have to take a look at the book later. "Clearly" for Mumford can mean something else to mere mortals.

Comment: I'll think about it a little more, thanks!

Comment: @Hoot: I think you're fine.  Just looking at what's written in the page of Mumford displayed above, it seems that he takes $X$ to be irreducible, so indeed $U$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: I understand why U is dense in X, but how, from that, do we get F(x)=0 (hence f(x)=0) for all x in U implies f(x)=0 for all x in X?

Comment: The vanishing set of a regular function is closed, so F vanishing on U implies that F vanishes on X.

Comment: This all makes since, however is U dense in X even though we are considering the induced topology on X? Mumford says U is open in X, not in the ambient space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $F \in \mathcal O(U) = \bigcap_{x \in U} \mathcal O_x$ . Choose an arbitrary $x\in U$. Because $F\in \mathcal O_x$ set  $F = \frac{f}{g}$ with $f,g \in R$ and $g(x)\neq 0$. Set $V := U \cap \{x\in X: g(x)\neq0\}$. For all $z\in V$ holds $F(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = 0$. Hence $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in V$. The open set $V \subset X$ is dense because $X$ is irreducible. Hence $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in X$, i.e. $f = 0 \in R$. Hence $F = \frac{f}{g} = 0 \in \mathcal O_x \subset K$, q.e.d.

**Note**. The proof shows a strong type of identity theorem: For irreducible $X$ a rational function $F\in \mathcal O(U)$ vanishes iff its germ $F \in \mathcal O_x$ - not only its value $F(x) \in k$ - is zero for at least one point $x\in U$.

Comment: This makes sense, however Mumford seems to be saying that U is open in X, ie with the induced topology. Then in this case U need not be dense in X correct?

Comment: Any non-empty open subset $U$ of an irreducible algebraic set $X$ is dense in $X$. The topology in question is the Zariski topology. Proof: Assume $U \neq X$, set $U^c:= X \setminus U$. Apparently $X = U \cup U^c$. Take an arbitrary open subset $V \subset X$, $V \neq U$, $V \neq X$. In case $V \cap U = \emptyset$, we have $U \subset V^c$, hence $X \subset V^c \cup U^c$. As a consequence $X=V^c \cup U^c$ is the union of two smaller closed subsets, contradicting $X$ being irreducible. As a consequence $V \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Because $V$ is arbitrary, we get $U \subset X$ is dense, q.e.d.

Comment: That makes since, however what Mumford seems to do is define closed subsets in X, the irreducible algebraic subset, as being of the form V(A) := {x in X | f(x)=0 for all x in A}, A being an ideal of R:= k[x1,...,xn]/I(X). Then does an open subset of X, say U=X-V(A), still need to be dense in X?

Comment: My question is, is X still "irreducible" if it is considered as the topological space itself?

Comment: Yes, it is. The Zariski topology of $X$ is induced from the Zariski topology of $k^n$.

Comment: I was looking back over this problem, and realized that it is not necessarily true that, as you said, F=f/g where g(x) is nonzero for x in U. The representation of F as a quotient can vary from point to point at which it is evaluated, correct?

Comment: Mumford gives an example of this phenomenon on page 21, if you have the book. Namely, he uses the irreducible algebraic set X=V(xw-yz) in k^4.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a gap. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks!